# What's the insert complexity of btree?

Tags: algorithm, b-tree

It seems when new node is inserted(whose complexity is O(logN)), the whole tree needs to be re-balanced.

What's the complexity of re-balancing?

Answer (score 2):

It's the height of the tree. It's not rebalanced in the sense of a binary tree. When you add a node, if that causes a split you insert a key into the node above. If that causes as split, then you do the same thing one level up, etc., until you get to the root. So the complexity is O(logN).

Comment: How is it rebalanced in the sense of a binary tree?

Comment: In a height balanced binary tree (AVL tree), an insertion can affect more nodes than the ancestors of the leaf node. Here's a good animation:  http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~goodrich/dsa/trees/avltree.html